# How to iterate over dataset's "rows" (aka "observations")

Tags: matlab

I have a `dataset` object `ds` which has `A`, `B`, and `C` among its "variables" (aka "columns").

For each `r` "row" (aka "observation") in `ds`, I can construct a "signature" from the values of `A`, `B`, and `C` for `r` (as a cell array, for example).

In general, multiple "rows" of `ds` can have the same signature.  Hence this signature, as it stands, could not be construed as a "key" for the table of observations stored in `ds`, but I could extend the signature to include one additional (new) variable `D` representing the number of times that the row's particular combination of `A`-, `B`-, and `C`-values has appeared in the dataset *"so far"* (i.e. as one iterates over the rows/observations in the dataset).  To do this, however, I need to be able to iterate over the "rows" of `ds`, which I have not been able to figure out how to do.

Can someone show me how one can iterate over a dataset's *rows* (*observations*)?

(I realize that such iteration is probably slow, but I can't think of any way around it if I'm going to construct the new `D` "variable"/"column".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat your dataset very much like a standard matlab structure, as shown in the examples in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/dataset-array-columns.html). As such, for your case you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
count = containers.Map();
D = cell(1, size(ds,1));
for i = 1:size(ds,1) %for each observation
    signature = [ds.A(i) ds.B(i) ds.C(i)]; %or however you wish to generate the sig

    occurences = 1; %assuming we have not seen it before, we have one occurence
    if count.isKey(signature) %if we have seen it before
        occurences = count[signature] + 1; %add one to the old count
    end
    D{i} = [signature occurences]; %make the complete signature
    count[signature] = occurences; %update our count map
end
ds.D = D; %add the new variable to the map.
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming `ds` is a 2D matrix with 3 columns, you can simply use `for` loop

```
for rowIndex = 1:size(ds,1) % number of rows
    A = ds(ri,1); 
    B = ds(ri,2);
    C = ds(ri,3);
    % ....
end
```

Comment: Dataset is a class from the stats toolbox. Nevertheless your example may well work due to the way said class is implemented.